# Implementing the Backwards Euler method in python to solve a pendulum

Tags: python, math, numerical-methods, ode

I am trying to set up an implicit solver to a pendulum F and dF are defined as:

```py
def func(y,t):
    ### Simplified the Function to remove friction since it canceled out

    x,v = y[:3],y[3:6]
    grav = np.array([0.,  0., -9.8 ])
    lambd = (grav.dot(x)+v.dot(v))/x.dot(x)

    return np.concatenate([v, grav - lambd*x] )
def dF_matrix(y):

    n=y.size
    dF=np.zeros((6,6))

    xp=np.array([y[3],y[4],y[5]])[np.newaxis]

    mass=1.
    F1=0.
    F2=0.
    F3=-mass*9.8
    F=np.array([F1,F2,F3])[np.newaxis]

    phix=2.*y[0]
    phiy=2.*y[1]
    phiz=2.*y[2]
    G=np.array([phix,phiy,phiz])[np.newaxis]

    H=2.*np.eye(3)
    lambd=(mass*np.dot(xp,np.dot(H,xp.T))+np.dot(F,G.T))/np.dot(G,G.T)

    dF[0,3]=1
    dF[1,4]=1
    dF[2,5]=1
    dF[3,0]=(y[0]*F1+2*lambd)/mass
    dF[3,1]=(y[0]*F2)/mass
    dF[3,2]=(y[0]*F3)/mass
    dF[3,3]=phix*y[3]
    dF[3,4]=phix*y[4]
    dF[3,5]=phix*y[5]
    dF[4,0]=(y[1]*F1)/mass
    dF[4,1]=(y[1]*F2+2*lambd)/mass
    dF[4,2]=(y[1]*F3)/mass
    dF[4,3]=phiy*y[3]
    dF[4,4]=phiy*y[4]
    dF[4,5]=phiy*y[5]
    dF[5,0]=(y[2]*F1)/mass
    dF[5,1]=(y[2]*F2)/mass
    dF[5,2]=(y[2]*F3+2*lambd)/mass
    dF[5,3]=phiz*y[3]
    dF[5,4]=phiz*y[4]
    dF[5,5]=phiz*y[5]

    return dF
```

I am trying to set up an implicit solver that uses the function and the dF in order to guess values in order to create a more accurate solver for my pendulum function.

the error that I get is the following

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     line 206, in  test_function(backwards_Euler)
>     line 186, in test_function y1 = test_function(func, y0, t)
>     line 166, in backwards_Euler F = np.asarray(y[i] + dt * function(zold, time[i+1])-zold)
>     line 13, in func lambd = (grav.dot(x)+v.dot(v))/x.dot(x)

ValueError: shapes (3,6) and (3,6) not aligned: 6 (dim 1) != 3 (dim 0)

I think it is because one of the calculations I am doing is diverging to infinity but I cannot figure out the issue that might be causing this.

Here is my current backward Euler function:

```py
### Backwards Euler Method

def backwards_Euler(function, y_matrix, time):
    y = np.zeros((np.size(time), np.size(y_matrix)))
    y[0, :] = y_matrix

    dt = time[1] - time[0]

    for i in range(len(time-1)):
        err = 1
        zold = y[i] + dt*function(y[i],time[i])  ## guess with forward euler
        I = 0

        while err > 10**(-10) and I < 5:
            F = y[i] + dt * function(zold, time[i+1])-zold  ## Here is where my error occurs
            dF = dt*dF_matrix(y[i+1])-1
            znew = zold - F/dF
            zold = znew
            I+=1
        y[i+1]=znew
    return y
```

Here is how I am testing the function although currently, I have no output

```py
# initial condition
y0 = np.array([0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.8, 0.0, 1.2])


def test_function(test_function):
    print(test_function.__name__ + "...")
    nt = 2500
    time_start = process_time()
    # time points
    t = np.linspace(0, 25, nt)
    # solve ODE
    y1 = test_function(func, y0, t)
    time_elapsed = (process_time() - time_start)
    print('elapsed time', time_elapsed)
    # compute residual:
    r = y1[:, 0] ** 2 + y1[:, 1] ** 2 + y1[:, 2] ** 2 - 1
    rmax1 = np.max(np.abs(r))
    print('error', rmax1)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')
    ax.plot3D(y1[:, 0], y1[:, 1], y1[:, 2], 'gray')

    plt.show()


test_function(backwards_Euler)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the error is that the matrix shapes in some matrix operations don't match. The immediate cause is that `x.dot(x)` works when `x` is a simple array, but not for two-dimensional arrays. Then the rules of matrix multiplication have to be strictly obeyed.

However, there is no reason that there is a matrix in place of `x`, you do not call the function in a "vectorized" fashion. The true reason is that python is not Matlab, the division in

```
znew = zold - F/dF
```

does not do what you think it does. Instead it does elementwise division, repeating the smaller object to fill the shape of the larger, which also happens with the subtraction, so that `znew` in the end has the same shape as the matrix `dF`, with the observed results in the next ODE function evaluation.

You need to explicitly invoke a linear solver, the standard one in in `np.linalg` (there are others there and in `scipy.sparse.linalg` using other matrix factorizations) is simply called `solve(A,b)` and computes the solution of `A*x=b`.

```
znew = zold - np.linalg.solve(dF, F)
```

---

Implicit Euler gives a diverging solution, the length of the pendulum increases rapidly. Applying these methods to the similar implicit trapezoidal method, which is also Adams-Moulton 2nd order, gives the code

```py
def Adams_Moulton_2nd(function, y_init, time):
    # solve F(z)=0 with simplified Newton, where
    # F    = y + 0.5*dt*(f(y,t)+f(z,t+dt)) - z
    # is the defect of the implicit trapezium method. Using the derivative
    # dF_z = 0.5*dt*df_z(z,t+dt) - I
    # the non-linear solver step is solution of the linear system
    # dF_z*dz = -F
    y = np.zeros((np.size(time), np.size(y_init)))
    y[0, :] = y_init
    Id = np.eye(len(y_init))
    dt = time[1] - time[0]
    dt4 = dt**4

    for i in range(len(time)-1):
        f_0 = function(y[i],time[i])
        norm_0 = sum(f_0**2)**0.5 + 1e-6
        z = y[i] + dt*f_0  ## guess with forward euler
        dF = 0.5*dt*dF_matrix(z, t[i+1]) - Id
        for I in range(5):
            F = y[i] + 0.5*dt * (f_0+function(z, time[i+1])) - z
            dz = - np.linalg.solve(dF,F)
            if max(abs(dz)) < norm_0*dt4: break
            z += dz
        y[i+1]=z
    return y### Adams_Moulton_2nd
```

Comment: did you mean to say znew in your second code block? Also when I attempt to use the ```np.linalg.solve()``` function it tells me I cannot because it is a singular matrix.

Comment: I assume this is because there is something wrong with the way that I fill in my matrices

Comment: No, what is wrong is how you use the matrix. As I said, numpy/scipy is not matlab, the operator overloading there does not translate directly to the operator behavior here.

Comment: Is there a way I can accomplish what I want to by using a different function in python?

Comment: It really works that way, however it fails spectacularly at following the solution. Enhancing this by some minimal changes to implement the implicit trapezoidal method results in a quite good result in-between but closer to modified Euler than AB2.

Comment: how would I go about doing the implicit trapezoidal method? I see how its basic form would be similar but where would I integrate the dF_matrix() into this?

Comment: You are solving `z = y + dt/2*(f(y,t) + f(z,t+dt)`, so in the same way `F=y + dt/2*(f(y,t) + f(z,t+dt) - z` and `dF_z = dt/2* df_y(z,t+dt) - I`. Note that `I` has to be the identity matrix, `np.eye(len(z))`, subtracting `1` results in subtracting one from every matrix element.

Comment: I see my mistake with the identity matrix but how does this avoid the issue with the solve() function in numpy?